# Bearer Token Authentication not working in VSTS build

Tags: c#, azure, tfs, continuous-integration, azure-devops

I'm trying to set up Continuous integration and deployment.

I have an authorization server already deployed and working in another azure app, I'm testing my API which uses OAuth 2 authentication, I'm passing the bearer token to my httpclient and this works ok if I run all my integrations tests locally, however on the VSTS build I always get Forbidden as my api response status code, I can confirm that I'm succesfully getting my accestoken but I can't confirm that on VSTS this is being sent on my http request.

below is my build definition

[image]

Is there a way to debug a build on VSTS? or does somebody know why the authentication is not working on the VSTS buid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, VSTS works just fine, only that the API was stopped on Azure and it returns the same status code **403** for Site not Available and for Forbidden

The API was stopped on Azure due to issues with releasing the lock to be able to publish the app.